# AngularJs: to Propagate event between directives by $emit

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have under one controller two directives :

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
   <div data-dy-items-list items="items"></div>           // FIRST DIRECTIVE
   <div data-dy-subitems-list subitems="subitems"></div>  //SECON DIRECTIVE
</div>
```

In the Second directive template, I have one button and in the directive.js file in the controller section I did this :

```
$scope.clickButton= function () {
 ......
$scope.$emit("UPDATE_PARENT","updated");

}
```

In the first directive, I would like to do this in the controller section:

```
$scope.update = false;
    $scope.$on("UPDATE_PARENT", function (event,message){
                    $scope.update = true;
                    console.log('update: ' + $scope.update);
                });
```

But it doesn't work!!!

Answer (score 7):

`$emit` dispatches an event **upwards** through the scope hierarchy. Your directives are siblings and thus `$emit` won't work.

The solution might be to `$broadcast` an event from a parent scope. Do it from `ctrl` if that's an option for you, or inject `$rootScope` to the directive and do `$rootScope.$broadcast` from there:

```
$rootScope.$brodcast("UPDATE_PARENT","updated");
```

**Mind that `$broadcasting` events from `$rootScope` might seem to be an anti-pattern for AngularJS**. It strongly depends on the usecase. There are other solutions to your problem:

- One of them is to create a parent directive for both of your directives.
- Another one is to use an intermediatory `service` which will hold values. Then you can do `$watch` on the service data and react accordingly.
- You can `$emit` the event to the `ctrl` and then `ctrl` will `$broadcast` it down to the other directive.

Choose whatever fits your needs best.

Comment: pointing out a `$rootScope` gotcha: broadcasting down will trigger _every_ listener inside it, regardless of the scope from which it was "sent back" to the root.  so if you have multiple instances of a listener on the same event they'll activate.  ex) `<root> <scope1 listen-for="myevent" /> <scope2 listen-for="myevent"> <trigger e="myevent" /> </scope2> </root>` http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/a1gm7q4u/

Answer (score 2):

I just got same problem.

Event between two directives was now passed, not with scope.$emit, not with scope.$broadcast.

After looking around, I did this trick,
Use scope.$parent.$broadcast with your $parent scope:

Directive 1:

```
scope.$parent.$broadcast('NO_LIVE_CONNECTION', {});
```

Directive 2:

```
scope.$on('NO_LIVE_CONNECTION', function (event, params) {
  console.log("No live DB connections ...");
  scope.state.showErrorMessage = true;
});
```